# RaphaelJS Zooming Broken in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, raphael, scale

I've created a `resize` handler for a circle shape on a Raphael canvas that used to work fine across browsers, but now fails only on Chrome and produces a strange behavior:

when changing the window's width, at some point the circle gets "squished" and looses its proportions.

you can reproduce it using [this demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WgTuF/1/), by dragging the resize handle of the Results panel to change its width.

Comment: Sooo, I tried to use chrome in ubuntu. It works fine with the above example.... I was thinking about closing this question; however, I feel like other people may at some point have similar issues.

Comment: no, leave it on...this is something worth investigating. I could replicate it on Chrome on Win7

Comment: On Win XP: reproduced on Chrome 19.0.1084.36 beta-m. Working fine on IE7, IE8, Safari 5.0.4, Opera 11.62, and FireFox 11.

Comment: You've got a lot of things going here: jQuery, iframe and chrome. The fault may be easier to locate if eliminating some of these sources. I tried to remove the jQuery call, however that did not seem to help. Same with iframe. The problems persists with chrome AFAICT.

Comment: @andersand this is as much as I could widdle the issue down. I had the same issue in a larger project. I can confirm that it works in other browsers and in chrome with OSX and with Safari. This is a problem with chrome. I submitted a ticket for it: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=125608

The biggest issue is actually that it does not behave the same way in chrome across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Maybe it was a bug in one particular version of chrome. I think you can move past that now.

(Using Chrome 24 on OS X 10.8.2)

Comment: Specifically on windows. As mentioned it works fine in osx and linux. Windows + chrome + resizing svg breaks.